# If the sequence $a_k$ satisfies that $a_1=1,a_2 = 2;a_k-4a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2} =0$, ($k \ge 3$)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have applied $k=3,k=4,k=5$ and found out that $a_3=5,a_4=14,a_5=41$. I cant find $a_k$, $(k>=1)$
please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please reformat your question to make it clear? Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To obtain $a_3$, I get from your recurrence $a_0 a_3  + 3a_2  = 0$. I need $a_0$ to proceed.

Comment: @ Gary. $ a_0 a_3  + 3a_2  = 0$ is not correct. For $a_3$ you need only $a_1$ and $a_2$: We have $a_3=4a_2-3a_1.$

Comment: @Fred The OP changed the question. It was $a_{n - 4} a_{k - 1}$ and not $
a_n  - 4a_{k - 1}$ originally.

Answer (score 2):

For $$a_k-4a_{k-1}+3a_{k-2} =0$$ the characteristic equation is
$$r^2-4r+3=0=(r-1)(r-3)$$ So,as usual, the solution is
$$a_k=c_1 (1)^k+c_2(3)^k$$ Use the conditions to get $c_1$ and $c_2$